# When catch block statements will appear

Tags: java, exception, error-handling

I'm writing programs for 2 years as a student. I'm just curious when the catch statements will appear. I tried everything to make my program output the statements inside the catch block but I fail. Any ideas?

```
try{
    System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");
      String sentence = dataIn.readLine();
      String res = sentence.replaceAll(" ", "");
    System.out.println(res);
  }catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.err.println(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `throw new IOException` like

```
try {
    throw new IOException("Like this");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.err.println(e);
}
```

Output is

```
java.io.IOException: Like this
    at com.stackoverflow.Main.main(Main.java:8)
java.io.IOException: Like this
```

Comment: Is it possible to show the statements inside without 'throw new exception'?

Comment: @Patrick Sure, but something has to throw an Exception. If you want it to always run then you need a `finally` block.

Comment: ohh thank you sir I see. The finally block always executes when the try block exits -docs.oracle. Thanks for enlightening me.

Answer (score 1):

It will be triggered when the code inside it throws an `IOException`

You can force that to happen quite simply with something like this:

```
try{
    System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");
    String sentence = dataIn.readLine();
    String res = sentence.replaceAll(" ", "");
    System.out.println(res);
    throw new IOException("Testing");
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.err.println(e);
}
```

Whatever your `dataIn` object is could well throw one too, eg if the stream it was reading from gave an error

Comment: What kind of input will be needed in order trigger the catch block?

Comment: Probably isn't about the input, it's the stream / network / file / computer / etc that it's coming from

Comment: Nice sir it's clear to me now about how the exception handling works. Thank you.